# break for of loop with recursion

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I have a function that takes a node and an object. The larger object potentially has property of `children` and that is an array of similar shaped nodes. The function is looking at the top level, and then if there are children look through each of those until the matching node is found.

My `console.log` statement always logs something. But the function keeps running. I belive it isn't breaking the loop of looking at the rest of the children.

What am I missing to completely exit this function when a match is found?

```
findNodeInStateHierarchy = (node, stateHierarchyNode) => {
    if (node.id === stateHierarchyNode.id) {
      console.log(stateHierarchyNode);
      return stateHierarchyNode;
    }
    else {
      if (stateHierarchyNode.children) {
        for (let child of stateHierarchyNode.children) {
          this.findNodeInStateHierarchy(node, child);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findNodeInStateHierarchy = (node, stateHierarchyNode) => {
    if (node.id === stateHierarchyNode.id) {
      console.log(stateHierarchyNode);
      return stateHierarchyNode;
    } else {
      if (stateHierarchyNode.children) {
        for (let child of stateHierarchyNode.children) {
          const result = this.findNodeInStateHierarchy(node, child);
          if (result !== null) {
              return result;
          }
        }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```